# Derivation of Kravchuk polynomial identity

Tags: coding-theory, orthogonal-polynomials, association-schemes

I am working my way through [N.J.A. Sloane "An Introduction to Association Schemes and Coding Theory"](https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-12-064850-4.50009-4) and have got stuck proving the last of his identities for the Kravchuck (Krawtchouk) polynomials.  The Kravchuk polynomial is defined as
$$
K_k(i;n) = \sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^j \binom{i}{j} \binom{n-i}{k-j}
$$

I know (have proved) the following equivalent formulations
$$
K_k(i;n) = \sum_{j=0}^k (-2)^j \binom{i}{j} \binom{n-j}{k-j} \\
=  \sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^j 2^{k-j} \binom{n-k+j}{j} \binom{n-i}{k-j}\\
$$

I know that if $u \in \mathbb{F}_2^n$ has weight, $wt(u)=i$ then
$$
K_{k}(i;n) = \sum_{v \in \mathbb{F}_2^n \\ wt(v) = k} (-1)^{u \cdot v}
$$

I know that $K_k(i;n)$ is the coefficient of $z^k$ in $(1+z)^{n-i}(1-z)^{i}$.  I know the orthogonality conditions:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n} \binom{n}{i} K_k(i;n) K_l(i;n) = 2^n\binom{n}{k} \delta_{k,l}
$$

I have also proved the following properties
$$
\binom{n}{i} K_k(i;n) = \binom{n}{k} K_{i}(k;n) \\
(k+1)K_{k+1}(i;n) = (n-2i)K_k(i;n) - (n-k+1)K_{k-1}(i;n) \\
\sum_{j=0}^k K_j(i;n) = K_k(i-1;n-1)
$$

But I am really stuck on proving this one
$$
\sum_{\ell =0}^n \binom{n-\ell}{n-j} K_{\ell}(i;n) = 2^j \binom{n-i}{j}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another proof I worked out for the case that $0 \leq i \leq n$ is an integer.  It uses the binomial expansion
$$
(a+b)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} a^k b^{n-k}
$$
in two places and the fact that when $i$ is an integer in the given range
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n} K_k(i;n) y^k = (1+y)^{n-i}(1-y)^{i}.
$$

We want to show that
$$
-2^j\binom{n-i}{j} + \sum_{\ell=0}^{n} \binom{n-\ell}{n-j} K_{\ell}(i;n) = 0
$$
for all $0 \leq j \leq n$. We form the generating function whose coefficient of $z^j$ is the left hand side of the desired identity:
$$
F(z) = \sum_{j=0}^{n} \left(-2^j\binom{n-i}{j} + \sum_{\ell=0}^{n} \binom{n-\ell}{n-j} K_{\ell}(i;n)\right) z^j \\
 = \sum_{j=0}^n -(2z)^j \binom{n-i}{j} + \sum_{j=0}^n \sum_{\ell=0}^{n} \binom{n-\ell}{n-j}K_{\ell}(i;n) z^j \\
= -(1+2z)^{n-i} + \sum_{j=0}^n \sum_{\ell=0}^{n} \binom{n-\ell}{n-j}K_{\ell}(i;n) z^j \\
= -(1+2z)^{n-i} + \sum_{\ell=0}^{n} \sum_{j=0}^n \binom{n-\ell}{n-j}K_{\ell}(i;n) z^j \\
= -(1+2z)^{n-i} + \sum_{\ell=0}^{n} K_{\ell}(i;n) \sum_{j=0}^n \binom{n-\ell}{n-j} z^j \\
= -(1+2z)^{n-i} + \sum_{\ell=0}^{n} K_{\ell}(i;n) z^{\ell} \sum_{j=0}^n \binom{n-\ell}{n-j} z^{j-\ell} \\
= -(1+2z)^{n-i} + \sum_{\ell=0}^{n} K_{\ell}(i;n) z^{\ell} (1+z)^{n-\ell} \\
= -(1+2z)^{n-i} + (1+z)^n \sum_{\ell=0}^{n} K_{\ell}(i;n)\left( \frac{z}{1+z}\right)^{\ell}.
$$
Letting $y = z/(1+z)$, we get
$$
F(z) = -(1+2z)^{n-i} + (1+z)^n \left(1+z/(1+z) \right)^{n-i} \left(1-z/(1+z) \right)^{i} \\
 = -(1+2z)^{n-i} + (1+z)^n (1+2z)^{n-i} (1+z)^{i-n} (1+z)^{-i} \\
 = -(1+2z)^{n-i} + (1+2z)^{n-i} \\
 = 0. \\
$$
Since $F(z) = 0$ the coefficient of $z^j$ in $F(z)$ is $0$ for all $0 \leq j \leq n$.  Going back to the definition of $F(z)$ and extracting the coefficient of $z^j$ gives
$$
-2^j\binom{n-i}{j} + \sum_{\ell=0}^{n} \binom{n-\ell}{n-j} K_{\ell}(i;n) = 0.
$$
as desired.

Comment: In general ${n-\ell\choose n-j} \ne 0$ when $\ell\gt n$ for example ${-3\choose 3} = -10$ because the binomial coefficient is $(n-\ell)^{\underline{n-j}}/(n-j)!.$

Comment: You are right, thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 2):

Defining the Kravchuck polynomial as (the definition in its full
generality is at
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kravchuk_polynomials))

$$\mathcal{K}_k(x;n) =
\sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^j {x\choose j} {n-x\choose k-j}$$

we seek to show that

$$\sum_{\ell=0}^n {n-\ell\choose n-m} \mathcal{K}_\ell(x; n)
= 2^m \times {n-x\choose m}.$$

We prove this for $x=p$ an integer and then it holds for all $x$
because $\mathcal{K}_k(x;n)$ is a polynomial in $x.$

We have

$$\mathcal{K}_k(p; n) = [z^k] (1+z)^{n-p}
\sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^j {p\choose j} z^j.$$

Here the coefficient extractor enforces the upper limit of the sum and
we get

$$\mathcal{K}_k(p; n) = [z^k] (1+z)^{n-p}
\sum_{j\ge 0} (-1)^j {p\choose j} z^j
= [z^k] (1+z)^{n-p} (1-z)^p.$$

We also get for the coveted identity that it is

$$\sum_{\ell=0}^n {\ell\choose n-m} \mathcal{K}_{n-\ell}(p; n)
= \sum_{\ell=0}^n {\ell\choose n-m}
[z^{n-\ell}] (1+z)^{n-p} (1-z)^p
\\ = [z^n] (1+z)^{n-p} (1-z)^p
\sum_{\ell=0}^n {\ell\choose n-m}
z^\ell
\\ = [z^n] (1+z)^{n-p} (1-z)^p
\sum_{\ell=n-m}^n {\ell\choose n-m}
z^\ell
\\ = [z^m]  (1+z)^{n-p} (1-z)^p
\sum_{\ell=0}^m {\ell+n-m\choose n-m}
z^\ell.$$

Now here we have another coefficient extractor enforcing the upper
range of the sum and we get

$$[z^m]  (1+z)^{n-p} (1-z)^p
\sum_{\ell\ge 0} {\ell+n-m\choose n-m}
z^\ell
\\ = [z^m] (1+z)^{n-p} (1-z)^p \frac{1}{(1-z)^{n-m+1}}.$$

This is

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|=\varepsilon} \frac{1}{z^{m+1}}
(1+z)^{n-p} (1-z)^{m-1} \frac{1}{(1-z)^{n-p}} \; dz.$$

Now put $(1+z)/(1-z) = w$ so that $z = (w-1)/(1+w)$ and $dz = 2/(1+w)^2
\; dw$ to obtain (observe that due to the fact that $w=1+2z+\cdots$ the
image of a small circle  $|z|=\varepsilon$ can be deformed to another
small circle $|w-1|=\gamma$  because when $z$ makes one turn around zero
so does $w$ around one)

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|w-1|=\gamma}
\frac{(1+w)^{m+1}}{(w-1)^{m+1}}
w^{n-p} \frac{2^{m-1}}{(1+w)^{m-1}}
\frac{2}{(1+w)^2} \; dw
\\ = \frac{2^m}{2\pi i} \int_{|w-1|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{(w-1)^{m+1}} w^{n-p} \; dw
\\ = \frac{2^m}{2\pi i} \int_{|w-1|=\gamma} \frac{1}{(w-1)^{m+1}}
\sum_{r\ge 0} {n-p\choose r} (w-1)^r \; dw.$$

There were no poles other than $w=1$ inside the image contour and the
series in $w-1$ converges including for $n-p \lt 0$ because $\gamma\ll 1.$

This yields

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
2^m \times {n-p\choose m}}$$

as claimed.

Comment: Thanks Marko; I am working through this.  In the second equation after "We also get for the coveted identity that it is" shouldn't the exponent of $z$ in the sum be $-\ell$ not $\ell$?

Comment: No, $[z^{n-\ell}] f(z) = [z^n] z^\ell f(z).$

Comment: yes, of course.