# Alternative expressions for Krawtchouk (Kravchuk) polynomials

Tags: polynomials, binomial-coefficients, coding-theory, orthogonal-polynomials

For fixed non-negative integers $n$ and $q \geq 2$, the $k$-th Krawtchouk (Kravchuk) polynomial is defined as
$$K_k = \sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^j (q-1)^{k-j} \binom{X}{j} \binom{n-X}{k-j} \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$$
The definition is based on generalized binomial coefficients
$$\binom{a}{b} = \frac{a \cdot (a-1) \cdot \ldots \cdot (a-b+1)}{b!}$$
where $b\in\mathbb{N}$ and $a$ comes from any ring ($\mathbb{Q}[X]$ in our case) containing the rationals.

**Question**

The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kravchuk_polynomials) lists two alternative expressions for $K_k$:

$$K_k = \sum_{j=0}^k (-q)^j (q-1)^{k-j} \binom{n-j}{k-j}\binom{X}{j}$$

$$K_k = \sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^j q^{k-j} \binom{n-k+j}{j}\binom{n-X}{k-j}$$

I'm looking for elegant proofs of these alternative forms. Preferably in an elementary way or using the generating series (see again [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kravchuk_polynomials))

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty K_k Z^k = (1 + (q-1)Z)^{n-X} (1-Z)^X$$
where polynomial exponents are defined based on the binomial series
$$(1 + Z)^X = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \binom{X}{i} Z^i.$$

**Comment**

The alternative expressions have also been mentioned (without proof) [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4320991/61691) as well as [here (for $q=2$)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4131219/61691).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from

$$K_k = \sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^j (q-1)^{k-j}
{X\choose j} {n-X\choose k-j}$$

we first obtain

$$K_k = [z^k] (1+z)^{n-X}
\sum_{j\ge 0} (-1)^j (q-1)^{k-j} z^j {X\choose j}.$$

Here we have extended to infinity due to the coefficient extractor.
Continuing,

$$(q-1)^k [z^k] (1+z)^{n-X}
\sum_{j\ge 0} (-1)^j (q-1)^{-j} z^j {X\choose j}
\\ = (q-1)^k [z^k] (1+z)^{n-X}
(1-z/(q-1))^X
\\ = [z^k] (1+(q-1)z)^{n-X} (1-z)^X.$$

#### First identity

We seek to verify that

$$K_k = \sum_{j=0}^k (-q)^j (q-1)^{k-j} {n-j\choose k-j}
{X\choose j}.$$

We get for the sum

$$[z^k] (1+z)^n \sum_{j\ge 0} (-q)^j (q-1)^{k-j}
(1+z)^{-j} z^j {X\choose j}.$$

Here the coefficient extractor has once more enforced the range.
Continuing,

$$(q-1)^k [z^k] (1+z)^n \sum_{j\ge 0} (-q)^j (q-1)^{-j}
(1+z)^{-j} z^j {X\choose j}
\\ = (q-1)^k
[z^k] (1+z)^n \left[1-\frac{qz}{(q-1)(1+z)}\right]^X
\\ = [z^k] (1+(q-1)z)^n \left[1-\frac{qz}{1+(q-1)z}\right]^X
\\ = [z^k] (1+(q-1)z)^{n-X} [1+(q-1)z-qz]^X
\\ = [z^k] (1+(q-1)z)^{n-X} (1-z)^X.$$

This is the claim.

#### Second identity

Here we set out to simplify

$$K_k = \sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^j q^{k-j} {n-k+j\choose j}
{n-X\choose k-j}.$$

We get for the sum

$$[z^k] (1+z)^{n-X}
\sum_{j\ge 0} (-1)^j q^{k-j} {n-k+j\choose j} z^j.$$

This is the third time with the extractor enforcing the range.
Continuing,

$$q^k [z^k] (1+z)^{n-X}
\sum_{j\ge 0} (-1)^j q^{-j} {n-k+j\choose j} z^j
\\ = q^k [z^k] (1+z)^{n-X} \frac{1}{(1+z/q)^{n-k+1}}
= [z^k] (1+qz)^{n-X} \frac{1}{(1+z)^{n-k+1}}.$$

This is

$$\;\underset{z}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{z^{k+1}} (1+z)^{k+1} (1+qz)^{n-X}
\frac{1}{(1+z)^{n+2}}.$$

Now we put $z/(1+z)=w$ so that $z=w/(1-w)$ and $dz = 1/(1-w)^2 \; dw$
to get

$$\;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{w^{k+1}} (1+qw/(1-w))^{n-X}
\frac{1}{(1+w/(1-w))^{n+2}} \frac{1}{(1-w)^2}
\\ = \;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{w^{k+1}} (1+qw/(1-w))^{n-X} (1-w)^n
\\ = \;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\;
\frac{1}{w^{k+1}} (1-w+qw)^{n-X} (1-w)^X
\\ = [w^k] (1+(q-1)w)^{n-X} (1-w)^X.$$

Once more we have the claim.

Comment: Many thanks for this answer. What is 'res'?

Comment: This is the [complex residue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)) for use with [Egorychev method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egorychev_method).

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Very nice! (+1)